# Return array from PHP to JavaScript without JSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I'm trying to finish a school project but can't seem to find any solutions. I need to access a database, format the rows into an array, and then return it to a JavaScript file to be used to create a graphic using the Google Charts API.

I can't use PHP since I have to use the school's PHP server which is running PHP 5.1.6. I saw some code that allows you to use JSON on earlier versions of PHP but I'm not sure how to actually add that to my PHP file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why ***without*** JSON?...

Comment: I'm getting "Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_encode()"  I think its because the school's PHP server which is running PHP 5.1.6.

Comment: Depends on what the arrays look like.  Easiest is send a string of delimited values to js and split them into an array.

Comment: PEAR has a JSON library, try that?

Comment: @user3316362 You can try creating a page with `phpinfo();`. This gives a print out of your server and what plugins are installed. See if `json` is listed. If not, your server doesn't have the plugin installed. Probably the case here.

Comment: I tried phpversion(). Returned 5.1.6. Got it working. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print out the list of values separated by comma, then use split in Javascript:

```
var returnVars = xmlhttp.responseText.split(",");
for(var i=0; i<returnVars.length; i++)
{
     alert(returnVars[i]);
}
```

This is assuming an Ajax request.  If you're just writing the Javascript into the PHP, obviously its as simple as making the PHP code write out what the Javascript for an array would look like.

Comment: Didn't think to do that. I think i can make that work. Thank you!